# Rails 4: PG::ConnectionBad definition of service "postgresql" not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

My rails app can't seem to connect with my Postgresql database. It keeps giving me this error when I access it on localhost:3000.

```
PG::ConnectionBad  
definition of service "postgresql" not found
```

This even happens when I connect pgAdmin3 with my db and give the location of pg_service.conf file. If I leave the service field empty than I am able to connect successfully to my db.

So I just want to know why it isn't picking up my pg_services file and what am I missing here.

My pg_services.conf file is located in /etc/postgresql-common and it looks like this:

```
[postgres]  
dbname=postgres  
user=postgres  
password=postgres
```

All parameters are set intentionally meaning i have named my db postgres with user postgres and password postgres.

My database.yml looks like this:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  host: localhost
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: postgres
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: postgres

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: postgres

production:
  <<: *default
  database: postgres
```

And localhost connections are also allowed in postgresql.conf. Here is a snippet:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = 'localhost'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per
# connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql'           # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name
                                        # (change requires restart)
```

So why can't it still find pg_service.conf or am I missing some kind of directive in this file?

Comment: Linux? When you run `sudo -u postgres psql`, what happens?

Comment: @D-side Its kali linux an ubuntu variant. I tried `sudo -u postgres psql` and it launched the `postgres=#` prompt. So no problems there I guess.